# Creating an event-invite using the old REST API

Tags: facebook, api, rest

I cannot do the following with the Graph API, so I'm trying to do it with the old REST API,
but without any success... No error message, but also no invite.

```
$restApi = $facebook->api(array(
            'method'  => 'events.invite',
        'eid' => $eid,
            'uids' => $testuserId,
        'personal_message' => 'testing',
            'access_token' => $accesstoken,
    ));
    print '<pre>' . print_r($restApi, true) . '</pre>';
```

Or maybe some of you know a better way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a open Vote on Event Invites with Graph API at the FB Bugzilla http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=10070

And I think your problem is that you need an `array` of uids try:

```
$restApi = $facebook->api(array(
            'method'  => 'events.invite',
        'eid' => $eid,
            'uids' => array($testuserId),
        'personal_message' => 'testing',
            'access_token' => $accesstoken,
    ));
    print '<pre>' . print_r($restApi, true) . '</pre>';
```

-michael

Comment: i tryd it also with an array.. nothing. i will just send out a msg with the eventlink.. maybe it is the best solution.

but thx for the buglink.. maybe, the will add this feature someday.

Comment: `Please note: We are in the process of deprecating the REST API, and will be adding equivalent support to the Graph API for this method. You should continue to use this method until we announce support in the Graph API.`
I think it will be supported with graph api too, before the rest api will be removed.